# How to add multiple action button in same modal in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using Bootstrap Modal. I need multiple action button for different purpose in a single Modal. I already have two button close and ok . i need another called submit or save.

```
<div class="modal-body">  
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <select  class="form-control" data-ng-model="review.sessionid" ui-select2 class="comboselection">
            <option  data-ng-repeat="review in modalOptions.reviews"  value="{{review.oid}}">{{review.sessionName}}</option>
          </select>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <textarea class="form-control"  name="review.news" data-ng-model="review.news"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>     

</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
     <button id="btnsubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="modalOptions.ok(review)" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>{{modalOptions.actionButtonText}}</button>
    <button class="btn btn-deafult" data-ng-click="modalOptions.close()"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>{{modalOptions.closeButtonText}}</button>

</div>
```

Close button is for close the modal. ok button is pass the object in controller via result variable of `modalService.showModal(modalDefaults, modalOptions).then(function (result)` . Here is my controller..

```
 var modalOptions = {
                    closeButtonText: 'Cancel',
                    actionButtonText: 'Submit',
                    headerText: 'Review PMP',
                    reviews: reviewlist
            };

            var modalDefaults = {
                    templateUrl: 'app/partials/pmpReviewModal.html'
                };

                modalService.showModal(modalDefaults, modalOptions).then(function (result) {
                var sessionName = result.sessionName;
                 var session = result.news;
                console.log(sessionName);
            });
```

But my problem is that how can i add another button for pass object for another purpose to the controller ?

Comment: What is the issue you are getting when you are adding other buttons ?

Comment: Nothing happen to controller.... i mean no hit

Comment: Does your action button or close buttons working fine ? I mean are you getting the hit ?

Comment: Yes.. i put console on the controller .. that works fine

Comment: can you please share any fiddle or plunker link so that i can help you out in better ways.